# Is there a dropdown menu as a component? Cannot find one online

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make a website, which is accessible to download pdf and mp3 files of sermons but I am not able to do this because I cannot find a way how to make a drop down menu thing.

I tried looking it up going on bootstrap, W3schools etc to no avail.

```
<script>

    function myFunction() {
        document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
    }

    window.onclick = function(event) {
        if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
            var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
            var i;
            for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
                var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
                if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
                    openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
                }
            }
        }
    }
</script>


<li>
    <ul>
        <div class="dropdown">
            <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">Lesson </button>
            <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
                <a href="#" download>Lesson PDF</a>
                <a href="#" download>MP3 File</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <div class="dropdown">
            <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">Lesson </button>
            <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
                <a href="#" download>Lesson PDF</a>
                <a href="#" download>MP3 File</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <div class="dropdown">
            <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">Lesson 3</button>
            <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
                <a href="#" download>Lesson PDF</a>
                <a href="#" download>MP3 File</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <div class="dropdown">
            <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">Lesson 4</button>
            <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
                <a href="#" download>Lesson PDF</a>
                <a href="#" download>MP3 File</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <div class="dropdown">
            <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">Lesson 5</button>
            <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
                <a href="#" download>Lesson PDF</a>
                <a href="#" download>MP3 File</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <div class="dropdown">
            <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">Lesson 6</button>
            <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
                <a href="#" download>Lesson PDF</a>
                <a href="#" download>MP3 File</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </ul>
</li>
```

This is the best I can do, but it is not good enough for me.

Comment: It's called a `select` tag. https://www.w3docs.com/learn-html/html-select-tag.html

Comment: Are you using react? Don't give any elements the same ID. You have multiple divs with myDropdown ID.

Comment: What is your CSS??

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap does have drop downs.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/dropdowns/

W3Schools (although I wouldn't go there) does also

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_dropdowns.asp

Answer (score -2):

You can find multiple components via Polymer.
For example: `https://www.webcomponents.org/search/dropdown`